When does the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Part 2 (Evaluation Theorem) Hold Across Unbounded Regions of Functions
The second part of the fundamental theorem of calculus is generally stated:
If $F^\prime(x) = f(x)$ on $(a,b)$ and $f$ is Reimann integrable on $(a,b)$ then $\int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b)-F(a)$.
Inherently, the requirement that $f$ be Reimann integrable assumes it is bounded and the requirement that $F^\prime = f$ assumes $f$ is defined across the entire interval. However, it seems that sometimes the second part of the fundamental theorem of calculus holds even when $f$ does not satisfy these requirements.
Consider $f = x^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ on $(-1,1)$. We see that $f \rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0$. So $f$ is unbounded and thus not Reimann integrable on intervals over $0$. However, $\forall x \neq 0, F(x) = 3(x^\frac{1}{3})$ has $F^\prime(x) = f(x)$. Notice $F(1) - F(-1) = 3+3 = 6$.
Now let us integrate $f$ as an improper integral: $$\int_{-1}^1x^{-\frac{2}{3}}dx = \int_{-1}^0x^{-\frac{2}{3}}dx + \int_0^1x^{-\frac{2}{3}}dx = \lim_{a\rightarrow 0^-} \int_{-1}^ax^{-\frac{2}{3}} dx + \lim_{b\rightarrow 0^+}\int_b^1x^{-\frac{2}{3}}dx = \lim_{a\rightarrow 0^-} 3(a^\frac{1}{3} + 1) +  \lim_{b\rightarrow 0^+}3(1 - b^\frac{1}{3} ) = 3+3 = 6$$
So we see a "naïve" application of the FToC on $f$ produces the correct result, despite not satisfying the requirements of the theorem. Is this a coincidence or is there a more relaxed version of the theorem which would account for such $f$?

Just to check: You do understand that it is fine for functions not satisfying the hypotheses of a theorem to satisfy the conclusions?  (I.e., the conclusion is guaranteed for functions satisfying the hypotheses and it's perfectly fine for the conclusion to apply to other functions.)

@EricTowers Yes of course, that is why I ask if the example I outline is a mere coincidence or if there is a deeper theorem which f does satisfy the hypotheses of.

Fairly certain the Henstock-Kurzweil integral will do this, although this is like hitting a fly with an over-large hammer.  Maybe a better Answer will appear.

You wrote $\sqrt{x^3}$, but you probably mean $\sqrt[3]{x^2}$. In fact the former is not even defined as a real number for negative values of $x$.

@peek-a-boo Yup, you're correct. Edited, thank you so much.
